# Android: Passing parameters into Activity from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

Does anyone know if it's possible to pass parameters into an Activity from the AndroidManifest.xml file? I want to use the same activity in a couple of apps, but have a way of conditioning the appearance of that activity based on the app.

E.g. I'd like to write something like (in AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <extradata>
              <item name="foo" value="bar"/>
        </extradata>
</activity>
```

.. and be able to read out the value of bar in the onCreate of the activity.  Is this something that can be done with the data attribute in an intent filter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, there is way to do just that. Check this article :

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/10/08/using-meta-data-in-an-androidmanifest/

In short you can get the content of the  tag using this :

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(),     PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
String myApiKey = bundle.getString("my_api_key");
```

Metadata tag is defined as this :

```
<meta-data android:name="my_api_key" android:value="mykey123" />
```

It is possible to access data in values, but if you want to specify something that is related to the activity, this is much cleaner approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, it works as expected, tested on API level 29. Perhaps it is worth mentioning, that <meta-data> item needs to be nested in the <application> item, not inside the <activity> as requested by the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use res/values/strings.xml

Save your data here. Use somethings like

```
<string-array name = "foo">
<item>bar1</item>
<item>bar2</item>
<item>red</item>
<item>blue</item>
<item>one</item>
<item>two</item>
</string-array>
```

you can then get this by using

```
Resources r;

r = getResources():

String[] foos = r.getStringArray(R.array.foo);
```

I think this is what your looking for. But if your looking to stylize your app then you should look at using a theme.

[android example for themes][1]

[1]: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html"THEME EXAMPLE"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this. (A bad hack might be to use the process name for the activity to signal something like this.) A much better approach would be to specify a standard resource in every one of your apps that contains the required info for the activity.